# Is this normal behavior when cancelling AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I cancelled my AWS account (free tier) and I got an email confirming the cancellation. I can still log into the billing console and my account settings though (where I can still cancel the account). Is this normal?

I also got an email with the confirmation of the cancellation of AWS support (basic). I have not subscribed to AWS support though. Is this normal?

How do I know that my account is really cancelled and no charges will occur? When I click on Lambda for example it says now that my account is suspended.

Thanks for any help and reading my question.
It's difficult to find this out and search engines are no help in this case.

Comment: Where/how did you cancel your account? Also, please note that the AWS Free Tier is merely a billing discount, there is no such thing as a "Free Tier account". Given that is says your account is suspended, the cancellation has probably taken place.

Comment: I think something similar happened to me. It takes a few days to complete.

Comment: I have cancelled through the account settings page, just like explained in the AWS help. Of course I know that only a couple of things are reduced in price, but it was a great start to test working with a cloud computing service.

Comment: I'd email AWS support. This question isn't really meant for Stackoverflow.